# Why does the iterator in foreach not work?

Tags: foreach

I've split an animated GIF into the frames and saved them as a PNG sequence. I use the `beamer` class and want to load the images from the sequence, replacing each other without an autostart animation.

```
\begin{frame}\frametitle{FooBar}
\foreach \x in {0,...,5} {
   \includegraphics<\x+1>[width=0.95\textwidth]{dbgp-setup2-\x.png}
}
\end{frame}
```

The compiler output says that

`Latexmk: Missing input file: 'dbgp-setup2-.png' from line`

The filename should be `dbgp-setup2-0.png`, `dbgp-setup2-1.png` etc.. Why does `\x` not work?

Comment: Welcome! Try `\foreach \x [count=\y] in {0,...,5} {
   \includegraphics<\y>[width=0.95\textwidth]{dbgp-setup2-\x.png}
}` The parser does not know that it should compute the argument of `<....>`, so you have to do that.

Comment: Are you sure `dbgp-setup2-0.png`, `dbgp-setup2-1.png`, ... are in the working folder?

Comment: @Werner yes they are. I've included `\graphicspath{ {./img/} }` before. The package graphicx is also loaded.

Comment: @Christian: The solution to the question seem to be related to `\foreach` that isn't defined. As such, the `\x` isn't defined, leading to the missing number in the image reference. For future reference, include a *complete*, yet *minimal* example that allows us to replicate the behaviour. Such a minimal, working example (MWE) should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` and allow the community to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing. For that, use images from [`mwe`](//ctan.org/pkg/mwe) and [`lipsum`](//ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) text, if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parser does not parse `\x+1`, so you need to do this yourself. In this case `\x+1` coincides with the count, so we can use this. (Of course I do not have your images so I renamed some standard images.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{FooBar}
\foreach \x [count=\y] in {0,...,3} {
   \includegraphics<\y>[width=0.95\textwidth]{dbgp-setup2-\x}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I made two mistakes. The first one was not including `\usepackage{pgffor}` and the second one was the one with `\x+1`. Thank you, everything's working fine now!

Comment: @Christian Glad to hear! (The first one is hard to detect since you did not show your preamble.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why doing the thing so complicated:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{FooBar}
\foreach \x in {0,...,3} {%
   \includegraphics<+>[width=0.95\textwidth]{dbgp-setup2-\x}%
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! What does the `<+>` exactly do? There is another detail that keeps the following images in position: `%`

Comment: @Christian It just tells beamer to use the object in another overlay